# reCAPTCHA Enterprise malformed token and invalid site key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, recaptcha

I'm trying to integrate reCAPTCHA enterprise into my Flask web application on the login page.

Initially, I added the reCAPTCHA checkbox to the login page and retrieve the token via the POST request "g-recaptcha-reponse" parameter as detailed in the [documentations](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-assessment#retrieve_token).

However, I keep getting an error when checking that the token is valid that says "MALFORMED" from the assessment response object as seen below...

```
# main Python code to get the token from the post request
recaptchaToken = request.form.get("g-recaptcha-response")

# response from Google using google-cloud-recaptcha-enterprise Python library
# action name: "projects/<project_id>/assessments/<action_id>" # Note that I hid the project_id and action_id for this question
# event {
#   token: "AW-bC4mm022xpjWh2zI7od65_YdX81M6XfBPW5wIJtr8s5XXIzZ6ojfTFl9PjRlDHo601Svqpuyn5E8WhDlcBswXnrPGDbtUHekXcw60deyb8w0wyk1gZA0mJ0Hx9eAhGMI"
#   site_key: "6LfpqZcgAAAAAC7RH7qroayHutXeXkpLuKY5iV6a"
# }
# token_properties {
#   invalid_reason: MALFORMED
#   create_time {
#   }
# }
```

I then decided to look for other solutions such as appending the token data to the form after `grecaptcha.enterprise.execute` and submit the form data to the backend but I got another error in the console as shown below...

```
// js code
grecaptcha.enterprise.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.enterprise.execute("6LfpqZcgAAAAAC7RH7qroayHutXeXkpLuKY5iV6a", {action: "login"}).then(function(token) {
        console.log(token);
    });
});

// Error in console
// Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid site key or not loaded in api.js: 6LfpqZcgAAAAAC7RH7qroayHutXeXkpLuKY5iV6a
//     at Array.<anonymous> (recaptcha__en.js:113:393)
//     at recaptcha__en.js:62:400
```

Furthermore, for some reason, I had to wrap my site key with quotations for the reCAPTCHA Enterprise javascript src link to avoid the "Bad Request 400" error that I get from Google.

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?render='6LfpqZcgAAAAAC7RH7qroayHutXeXkpLuKY5iV6a'"></script>
```

Left with no ideas to solve the errors, here I am on StackOverflow...

Edit #1: Looks like the malformed token is caused by enabling Web Application Firewall (WAF) Action Token during the creation of the reCAPTCHA Enterprise key...

Edit #2: This only happens if you've enabled the checkbox feature, after disabling it on a new key, everything works now!

Final edit:
So when reading the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/instrument-web-pages#html-button), only at the bottom of the page is where I realised you do not create an assessment when using WAF action-tokens or session-tokens.
Hence, this error only happens if you've enabled WAF action-tokens or session-tokens as it requires you to attach the token to the request header.
More details [here](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/implement-tokens).